# How to find if array contains <null> and "" values in ios

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am getting an array with null value. Please check the structure of my array below:

```
 (
    "< null>"
    ""
 )
```

but how can we find  when our array-list having this type of objects for this i wrote below code but not working please help me

### my code:-

```
if (DropDownBinNameArray.count > 0 && (![DropDownBinNameArray isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])) {

            NSLog(@"yes ur here");

        }else{
            NSLog(@"yes ur in else");
        }
```

Comment: This should be corrected from backend, do not try to manage it at app side.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense as you are testing if the array object itself is a null object, rather than if it *contains* a null object.

This will probably work (there is no need to test the array `count`):

```
if ([DropDownBinNameArray containsObject:[NSNull null]]) {
     // It's got a null object
}
```